# How to link google home graph concept in Firebase (realtime database)

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-smart-home

In google smart home app, you can assign a device to a place, for example - bedroom (could this be home graph concept?).

How can I identify my device's place in my database (Firebase)?

Comment: Hi, have you tried searching for your answer? Quick search for "google home device place in db" yielded this result (search for 'Labels' within the page): https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/concepts/homegraph

Comment: Hi ArielGro,I already tried hard to search.I know that we can assign devices to any place in google smart home app with UI but how can I know what device is assigned to where in database.Can we get a place tag from google smart home app? Or I don't worry about this problem due to using device id to store device state in my database??

Comment: Hi..
I got your question for review and tried to give you some initial help. I'm not familiar with Google Smart Home, but searching for your issue led me to the link I gave you. did you try it?

Answer (score 0):

The platform does not provide the partner with user-defined rooms and nicknames that the user defines in the Home Graph.

Comment: It means I can use API to get existed room information to design my database,right?
What API can I use ?

Comment: No you can't obtain that through the API.

Comment: I found https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/reference/rpc/google.home.graph.v1#device have room_hint and structure_hint attributes.Can I use them to implement device loaction?

Comment: You can send that value in the initial SYNC, but you don't get those values back.